# Can QWaitCondition spuriously wake up?

Tags: c++, qt, condition-variable

The official documentation does not say if `QWaitCondition` can spuriously wake up like the `std::condition_variable`. Imagine I have thread1:

```
//Thread no. 1
qmutex.lock();
someCondition = false;
qmutex.unlock();
qwaitcond.notify_all();
```

So my question is if it can be safely assumed that this code in other thread:

```
//Thread no. 2
if(someCondition)
    qwaitcond.wait(qmutex);
```

and this code:

```
//Thread no. 2
while(someCondition)
    qwaitcond.wait(qmutex);
```

are eqivalent? Or is there any other source of knowledge saying that they can wake up without `notify` and I should prefer the second sample?

Note: I am assuming wait in Thread 2 is reached before the notify in Thread 1 for sake of simplicity

Comment: They are not equivalent, even without taking spurious wakeups into consideration. There is nothing preventing code on the other side from notifying condition variable without changing the condition.

Comment: One should always prefer the second sample. Irrespective of whether spurious wakeup can happen or not, the wakeup from the wait state does not imply that the condition is true. It is always better to recheck the condition on wakeup to avoid spurious wakeups or simply programming errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find answer in book "Hands-On High Performance Programming with Qt 5" page 141. The author of the book writes that spurious wake is possible. For avoiding spurious wake you should double-check that the condition we were waiting for was really met, as in the following code:

```
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
while(!thereIsAFreeSlot())
{
 condition.wait(&mutex);
}
```

Link: [https://www.amazon.com/Hands-High-Performance-Programming-cross-platform/dp/1789531241](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1789531241)

Comment: Good point, I will correct the answer.